# How do you implement a timer that counts how long a user takes to submit a form on a page

Tags: javascript, laravel

I recently started coding in php using the laravel framework and was trying to implement stuff into an existing page. Instead of tracking how long a user is viewing a page, I'm trying to track how long it takes the user to submit the form starting from when they first click on an input box.

I have the form page created and was messing around with some basic JS scripts, but couldn't get it to work.

```
    <form id="form" method="POST" action="/contact">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6  col-12">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name  *" name="name" class="form-control input" required>
                <br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email *" name="email" class="form-control" required>
                <br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Phone *" name="phone" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
```

I want a timer to start counting up the moment a user clicks on one of the 3 input boxes (name, email, or phone) then stop counting once the user clicks submit.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted without anyone saying what's wrong with it in the comments?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find out what kind of questions Stack Overflow [is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) intended for. This question is [asking for a solution without attempting to show any work](https://can-i-haz.codes/). Please provide some code to help us work with you to find a solution. (Providing only markup when the actual solution has to be implemented JS- or PHP-side is not enough).

Comment: @wilks because voting only takes a click and writing takes time.

Comment: Any input is appreciated, even input on how to submit a question correctly. I'm new to web development and stackoverflow.

Comment: "*was messing around with some basic JS scripts, but couldn't get it to work.*" - Show that "messing around"; as stated, we need to see some effort from you. Question; do you need to display this timer? Or just record it? Cause this can be done pretty easily with timestamps.

Comment: @timLewis I was trying to find solutions online by comparing my goal to others, but couldn't find anything or I was just not looking correctly. I'll look into timestamps, I was just looking for a starting point to look at documentation and hopefully find a solution myself.

Comment: Makes sense, and that's a fine approach. Look into javascript event handlers (with or without `jQuery`), and see if you can get an alert displaying when an input is clicked and when your form is submitted; that should be a good starting point for this.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you, I'm starting to figure it out. Now to pass the time data into a database what method would you use? I was reading something about using ajax for server side stuff since JS is only client side.

Comment: Yup; AJAX is probably the way to go. Or, assigning the time variable to an `<input>` element in your form, then submitting it. Either approach will send the data to the server for persistence to a database.

Comment: You could write to db just before returning the view of the form, and after submiting the form, then calculate the difference between both times. Or with javascript, when the document is ready, start to count the time, till you submit the form (or click the button that submits the form)

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways to do this, the first and more easy is to save the timestamp when the onClick event occours, you can use a function like this:

**Send the start time**

Create a start field in your form:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="/contact">
<input type="hidden" id="start" name="start" value="0">
```

Use this function on onclick event:

```
function startValue(){
    const startEl = document.querySelector('#start');
    if (!startEl.value) {
        startEl.value = Date.now();
    }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.form-control').forEach(function(item){
    item.addEventListener('click',startValue);
});
```

The start time will be send to the server and there you can create the logic to extract the elapsed time.

**Send the time in seconds**

The second way is to create a "startCounter" function and call that in onclick event and them use the value on the form submit function:

In HTML add a hidden input:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="/contact">
<input type="hidden" id="seconds" name="seconds">
```

And create a function that increments the

```
let counter = 0;
let interval = 1000;  //1 second

function startCounter(){
    if (counter === 0) {
        setInterval(function(){
            counter++;
            document.querySelector('#seconds').value = counter;
        },interval);
    }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.form-control').forEach(function(item){
    item.addEventListener('click',startCounter);
});
```